# Joining tables and subqueries in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I know this question has been asked 1000s of times before but please bear with me as I have a slightly different scenarion.

Basically I have 2 MYSQL tables that I join (one called category and the other is products) and I create categories and subcategories menu in my PHP page using the following code:

```
<?php
$subcategories="";
$sql3="SELECT products.di_cat, GROUP_CONCAT(products.di_name) as di_name 
FROM products LEFT JOIN category ON products.di_cat=category.names 
GROUP BY products.di_cat";
$query3 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql3);
$existCount3 = mysqli_num_rows($query3);
if ($existCount3!=0) {

    while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query3, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

        $make_names = $row3["di_cat"];
        $make_model = $row3["di_name"];

        $subcategories = explode(",",$make_model);    

        print '<div class="col-md-3">
               <span class="mega-menu-sub-title">'.$make_names.'</span>
               <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">';

        foreach($subcategories as $sub){
            print '<li><a href="view.php?p='.$sub.'">'.$sub.'</a></li>';
        }

        print '</ul></li></ul></div>';
    }
}
?>
```

This works fine and as it should.

Now I have a column in my `products` table called url.

This column is for creating clean URLs and the content of is basically the products names without any spaces or special characters.

I would like to use this in my code above but I don't understand why every time I try to use the follwoing code, I only get 1 subcategory/product from each category being displayed in my PHP page even though I have 100s of products under each category!

This what i tried:

```
<?php
$subcategories="";
$sql3="SELECT products.di_cat, products.url, GROUP_CONCAT(products.di_name) as di_name 
FROM products LEFT JOIN category ON products.di_cat=category.names 
GROUP BY products.di_cat";
$query3 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql3);
$existCount3 = mysqli_num_rows($query3);
if ($existCount3!=0) {

    while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query3, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

        $make_names = $row3["di_cat"];
        $make_model = $row3["di_name"];
        $make_url = $row3["url"];
        $subcategories = explode(",",$make_url);
        print '<div class="col-md-3">
               <span class="mega-menu-sub-title">'.$make_names.'</span>
               <ul class="sub-menu">
                   <li>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">';

        foreach($subcategories as $sub){
            print '<li><a href="view.php?p='.$make_url.'">'.$sub.'</a></li>';
        }

        print '</ul></li></ul></div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Can someone please advice on this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It’s really difficult to work out what’s going on here. I think this is actually a SQL problem rather than anything to do with PHP/.htaccess. Can you try to make your question clearer?

Comment: Could it be that you need to use an aggregate function on `products.url`? Try `GROUP_CONCAT(products.url)` and see if it works. You also group by category, so you wont get the products in that category.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query